# Facing error while making a library with integration of Sinch

Tags: java, android

I have a little challenge when setting up Sinch in an external library. I am building a library that uses Sinch to make video calls. The app works well locally and I publish the library to Jitpack successfully. But when I  add my library to a host app and build project, I get this error.

> Could not GET
>   https://jitpack.io/com/github/Tremendoc/sinch-android-rtc-3.14.2/1.0.4.1/sinch-android-rtc-3.14.2-1.0.4.1.pom`.
>   Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.github.Tremendoc:audio-sdk:1.0.4.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version
}
```

Comment: Is your repository private?

Comment: @Birju Vachhani   No

Comment: Could you please add code of your gradle files?

Comment: @Birju Vachhani have added the grade code